# how to vectorize the following for loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

can any one help me to Vectorized this loop.
i have large Matrix and i want to replace all the pixel values whose length is less then some threshold Value For simplicity lets say

```
a = randi([1 5],10,10);
for i = 1:length(a)
    someMat=a(a==i);
    if length(someMat)<20
        a(a==i)=0;
    end
end
```

but its killing me.

Example:

```
  a = randi([1 5],10,10)
    a =
         5     2     1     5     5     5     2     2     3     2
         3     3     5     4     4     4     3     1     1     5
         5     1     3     5     3     3     4     1     3     1
         3     1     5     3     2     5     1     1     5     1
         1     1     4     3     4     3     4     4     5     1
         1     4     3     5     1     1     2     2     2     1
         3     3     5     2     4     1     1     3     2     4
         4     1     5     3     4     5     3     4     3     3
         5     3     5     5     4     3     1     3     4     1
         4     1     1     3     5     5     1     3     3     5
```

Result for Thresold 20

```
        5     0     1     5     5     5     0     0     3     0
        3     3     5     0     0     0     3     1     1     5
        5     1     3     5     3     3     0     1     3     1
        3     1     5     3     0     5     1     1     5     1
        1     1     0     3     0     3     0     0     5     1
        1     0     3     5     1     1     0     0     0     1
        3     3     5     0     0     1     1     3     0     0
        0     1     5     3     0     5     3     0     3     3
        5     3     5     5     0     3     1     3     0     1
        0     1     1     3     5     5     1     3     3     5
```

length of pixel 4 was 17 
length of pixel 2 was 10

i try it by some thing like

```
[nVal Index] = histc(a(:),unique(a)); %
nVal(nVal>20) = 1; % just some threshold value and assigning by some Number may be zero as well
```

But I dont Know how to replace the Index Values of the corresponding Pixal and apply reshape to get it in original form. Here Even i am not sure that i will get the same Matrix With Reshape . Please Help me.....
thanks

Comment: Could you give a small numerical example with input matrix and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
threshold_length = 20;
replace_value = 0;

u = unique(a); %// values of a
h = histc(a(:), u); %// count for each value
r = u(h<threshold_length); %// values to be removed
a(ismember(a,r)) = replace_value; %// remove those values
```

Answer (score 0):

I see @LuisMendo arrived at mostly the same solution quicker than I did, but an alternative to using `ismember` is to use more of what `unique` gives you:

```
threshold = 20;
[vals, ~, ix] = unique(a);   % capture the values and their indices
counts = histc(a(:), vals);  % count the occurrences of each value
vals(counts<threshold) = 0;  % zero the values that aren't common enough
a(:) = vals(ix);             % recreate the matrix with updated values
```